# Difference between wq and x in vi

Tags: save, vi, quit

I always using `:wq` to save a file. Today, I came to know that `:x` can be used to do that. But I didn't notice it in any vi-tutorial or vi-quick-reference. Is there any difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From

```
help :x

    *:x* *:xit*
:[range]x[it][!] [++opt] [file]
            Like ":wq", but write only when changes have been
            made.
            When 'hidden' is set and there are more windows, the
            current buffer becomes hidden, after writing the file.
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between those two is very simple-
:x saves changes to the file only if it has been modified while :wq changes the modification time no matter what.